# context vs context-mkiv tags

Tags: discussion

There are two tags used to indicate ConTeXt questions: [`context`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) and [`context-mkiv`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context-mkiv). Would it be better to rename the tags: `context` and `context-mkii` (for MkII related questions).

Context (pun intended): ConTeXt MkII refers to PDFTeX and XeTeX engines while ConTeXt MkIV refers to LuaTeX engine. For a few years now, the recommendation is to use ConTeXt MkIV. Few users still use MkII for existing projects.

So, I think that it is better to use the tag `context` for MkIV related questions (maybe even make it a synonym for `context-mkiv`) and use `context-mkii` for MkII related question.

If this is okay, what is the best way to go about retagging the questions? This is not as simple as just renaming the tags because some questions tagged with `context` are about MkII while others are about MkIV.

**EDIT**: I started making the changes. I thought that I'd proceed as follows:

1. Look at all questions that are tagged with **both** `context` and `context-mkiv`. Delete the `context-mkiv` tags. (there were about 300 such questions).
2. Go through all the questions that are tagged `context` and check if they need to be tagged as `context-mkii`.
3. Rename `context-mkiv` as `context`.

Now, as I edited the tags in about 10-15 questions by hand, I was wondering if there are any mod tools that can be used to do step 1 automatically?

Comment: I think you are one of the few people here who can make a judgement so I guess on one of those days which answer the unanswered is scheduled, bulk of these can be done.

Comment: @percusse: With "best way to go about retagging the questions", I meant, how to proceed so that the front page is not flooded with ConTeXt questions

Comment: I don'tt think there is any other way, that's why you can flood while there is already a flood happening with the event.

Comment: I don't think it would be too much of a flood there are only 334 context-mkiv questions which could be retagged to context in one go easily, then it's just a matter of looking through the context tagged questions and retagging any to context-mkii if needed but surely there can not be that many of those coming up now? (only 909 in total and most must surely be ok left tagged as context)

Comment: FWIW, SE staff can do mass retagging directly on the database (so no bumps); ping them in TL if necessary.

Comment: @Raphael: I realized that it is easier to crate tag synonyms. Now, it is just a question of going over all questions tagged `context` and see if any of them refer to context mkii.